# basic function of js with extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I make a code like the following in extjs ?

```
$('#tab-home-view ul li a').click(function (ev) {
   $('#tab-home-view ul li').removeClass('selected');
   $(ev.currentTarget).parent('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

EDIT :

```
Ext.select('#tab-home-view ul li a').click(function (ev) {
    Ext.select('#tab-home-view ul li').removeCls('selected');
    Ext.select(ev.currentTarget).parent('li').addCls('selected');
});

Uncaught TypeError: Ext.select(...).click is not a function
```

Comment: *Write* it? Not sure what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: Refer Ext JS APIs... For Ex: ``Ext.select('#tab-home-view ul li a')`` and then use ``Ext.get(this)`` to do anything else... But not sure what you want!

Comment: @FelixKling I don't success to make the code below in extjs

Comment: That's OK. If you actually explain the problem you have, and post the code you have so far, we might be able to help you. But we can't help you if we don't know what the issue is.

Comment: I want to use the click() function after Ext.select(my link) but it's not working (error message)

Comment: Post the code and error message. Don't you think the error message is important for finding out what the issue is?

Comment: ExtJS events on components are handled through `listeners` or `controllers` typically.  I'd recommend using that approach if possible.  Check this [fiddle for a very simple example with listeners](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/n18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a really unusual use of ExtJs, but you can try:

```
Ext.select('#tab-home-view ul li a').on('click', function (ev) {
    Ext.select('#tab-home-view ul li').removeCls('selected');
    Ext.get(ev.currentTarget).up('li').addCls('selected');
});
```

Comment: the last select is not working, the click is handled then the class is removed but the addcls function doesn't work. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Try `get` instead of `select`

Comment: it's working fine :) thank you. I edited your post with the good answer